# How to define the default name field suggestion in Visual Studio 2019 for c#

Tags: c#, ide, coding-style, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Given the class:

```
class BaseController
{
    BaseView _baseView;
    BaseModel _baseModel;
}
```

When using visual studio's suggested naming, it offers me the name `base`,  not `baseView`.  I've managed to add the `_` prefix through the options, text-editor, c#, Code Style. But I cannot see how to control the proposed field name suggestion.

I was wondering if this could be controlled so it would suggest `_baseView` and `_baseModel` etc.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Naming
   [image]
2. Click "Select manage styles"
   [image]
3. Click the "+" to add a new naming style
4. Fill in:
   Naming Style Title: "_camelCase"
   Required Prefix: "_"
   Capitalization: "camel Case Name"
   [image]
5. Select "OK"
6. Click the "+" to add a new Specification
7. In the new row select:
   Specification: "Private or Internal Field"
   Required Style: "_camelCase"
   Severity: "Suggestion"
   [image]
8. **Restart Visual Studio**

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have searched for the answer to this in many places.